# Generate a 10 MBit RS485 (UART) datastream with an USB device

Tags: serial-port, usb, uart, rs485

I need to generate a 10 MBit RS485 (UART) data stream with an USB device. Until now, I thought that the FT2232H perfectly suit but as far as I understand, the FT2232H can only generate 12 MBit or 8 Mbit as the subdividers are limited for the main divider 0 and 1.
The USB device should enumerate at the PC as serial interface which supports a baudrate of 10 Mbit.

So any idea which chip is suited for the specific task?

Thanks.

Comment: Full-speed USB requires a 48 MHz clock because its bit rate is 12 Mbps, so most USB devices you find will have a clock speed of 48 MHz, 72 MHz, or some divisor of those.  So it's actually pretty unlikely that you will find a device that gives you a 10 MHz serial baud rate.  Why do you need that?  You might need to have a USB connection that uses a more standard baud rate like 115.2 kHz, and then feed it into a custom microcontroller board clocked at some multiple of 10 MHz in order to convert the signal.

Comment: You can (theoretically) get 100Mbits (or even 1G) if you use USB to ethernet. Just saying. RS485 at 10Mbit only goes 50 feet, 100baseT goes 100m.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions; I need the 10 Mbit serial datastream to test an external device. Therefore I can't change the baudrate. What uC would be suited? The STM32 only supports 10.5 MBit ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally implemented a suitable solution.
Set the baud rate to 12 MBit and use 2 Stop and 1 parity bit. 
Implement a 12 MBit RS422 receiver in a CPLD or FPGA and connect it directly with the FT2232H. The CPLD/FGPA removes one stop bit and the parity bit.

Output the received data in the CPLD/FPGA with an regular 8N1 10 MBit RS422 sender. In total, this must be done twice but with 12 and 10 MBit being switched.

Works like a charm and the CPLD can even be a QFN32 Lattice iCE40 CPLD.